# Issue with pip, distribute, and setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools, distribute

I have a package that uses `distribute_setup.py` to use `distribute` in place of `setuptools` - so I have:

```
from distribute_setup import use_setuptools
use_setuptools()
```

at the top of the package's `setup.py` file. To demonstrate the issue, I've created a simple `setup.py` file with:

```
from distribute_setup import use_setuptools
use_setuptools()

import setuptools
print "PATH TO SETUPTOOLS", setuptools.__file__
```

If I now create a virtual environment with `virtualenv`, and try running `python setup.py` using `python` from the virtual environment, I get:

```
PATH TO SETUPTOOLS /Users/tom/tmp/debug/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/setuptools/__init__.pyc
```

which is what I expect - i.e. this is actually `distribute`. However, if I now try and install the 'package' with pip from the virtual environment:

```
pip install -e git://github.com/astrofrog/test_pip_distribute.git#egg=test_pip_distribute
```

I get:

```
PATH TO SETUPTOOLS /Users/tom/tmp/testenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/__init__.py
```

which is the 'vanilla' setuptools. Why is this happening? Does `distribute_setup.py` not play nicely with `pip`?

The test 'package' can be found here.

Answer (score 0):

Virtualenv installs setuptools by default and ignores global packages by default.

I haven't tested anything, but try either doing:
1) virtualenv testenv --distribute
2) virtualenv testenv --global-site-packages
3) Installing distribute in the virtualenv
4)
from setuptools import setup

setup(...
      install_requires=['distribute']
)

Comment: But interestingly, the case that I install the package into the virtualenv not using pip, it behaves properly, but using pip it does not. So it seems to be a pip rather than virtualenv issue. The ``distribute_setup.py`` script will install ``distribute`` into the ``virtualenv`` if it wasn't present.